# Response XML data on Public Restful Web service on Force.com platform

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, salesforce, force.com

I have tested the following code

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myservice')

global class MyService {
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        String name = RestContext.request.params.get('name');

        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Hello '+name);
    }
}
```

By default the return type is JSON. How can i change the response format to XML. I tried following
    RestContext.response..addHeader('Content-type','text/xml');
    RestContext.response..responseBody=Blob.valueOf(''+newcase.Id+'');

But still i am not getting response as XML

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `content-type` into the **Request** and not in the response.

e.g:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer sessionId" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @account.txt "https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/"
```

Also, you should define a [XML Namespaces](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm) that references any Apex namespace your method uses.

Take care about setting `Content-Type` in the response, it is not possible set that using `XML`.

> Some parameter and return types can't be used with XML as the
>   Content-Type for the request or as the accepted format for the
>   response, and hence, methods with these parameter or return types
>   can't be used with XML.

[More](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_methods.htm) detailed info